# SNS等に見られる「報告する」機能の実装について

Tags: ios

TwitterやYoutube,note等のSNSサービスには、コンテンツに対して「報告する」という機能が実装されています。この機能の理想的な実装方法・運用方法はどういったものになりますか？

Youtubeの「報告する」機能
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802027?hl=ja

上記リンクのような不正なコンテンツをユーザが報告することができる機能です。

現在簡単な実装で考えているものが、iOSアプリ上からユーザが「報告する」ボタンを押すと、APIを通してコンテンツの「報告数」カウントがアップデートされ、一定数以上の報告があったコンテンツに対しては、コンテンツ自体表示しなくする。または、アプリのUIから不正コンテンツとわかるようにする。というものですが、過去実装経験がないため正直少し不安です。

他サービスでこの機能をテストし、内部構造にあたりをつけるのが困難なためここで質問させていただきました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「理想的」と言われてもケースバイケースですが・・・大きく分けて、二種類でしょうか。

- 通報はあくまで参考情報でしかなく、最終的な判断は人間が行う

  組織票などの影響を受けず、逆に少ない通報でも早く対応することが可能です。しかし投稿数に比例して通報対応する人手が必要になります。YouTubeもこのタイプです。
- 多数決もしくは一定数の通報で自動的に削除される

  人が介入しないので運用が楽ですし、ある意味では基準が明確と言えます。一方で、適当な通報や組織票をどのように除外するかがネックです。

ガイドラインに沿っているかどうかや権利問題といった、統一判断を求められる場合には前者の方が適当でしょうし、「大勢の人が不快に思った質問を隠す」といった意味合いなら多数決もありでしょう。

例えばこのサイトの場合、通報はモデレーターに見えるため前者の扱いも可能ですし、[一定数の通報が集まれば自動的に削除される](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)こともあります。それ以前にクローズや削除が投票制になっていますが。

実装面で言えば、単純なカウンタではなく、同じユーザーからの多重通報を防ぐためにも「誰が通報したのか」を記録することが多いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 仰る通り「誰が通報したのか」は確実に把握する必要がありますね。前者の仕様と運用で走り様子を見ようと思います。ご回答ありがとうございました！とても参考になりました！